# Safe division function

Tags: c++

I would like to define some kind of safe division (and modulo) function, one that would return some predefined value when attempting to divide by zero. I don't want to throw exceptions, just to return some "reasonable" value (1? 0?) and continue the program flow. Obviously there is no correct return value, but I wonder if there is some standard or known approach to this

Comment: What is wrong with a try/catch block?

Comment: how about "int div( int a, int b, bool *bOK=0);"

Pass in a pointer-to-bool if you want to know whether the result was valid.

Comment: The worse the program blows up the better, the last thing I want is to let this pass unnoticed. There is no "reasonable" size for the pieces of an apple that's divided through no kids. The "standard approach" to this is to fix your error.

Comment: An apple divided through no kids may get rotten and its seeds may give a new tree which in turn may give apples which may give trees... In other words: infinity

Comment: Depending on why you are dividing, sometimes yielding an infinity rather than exploding is perfectly reasonable.  I honestly can not imagine a case where this is true of integral division, of course, since there is no infinite state for integers.

Comment: @Dennis Solution: define a type representing integers with infinity :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE floating point standard defines what to get from a [division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_computer_arithmetic).

- +a / +0 gives +Inf
- +a / -0 gives -Inf
- 0 / 0 gives NaN

If you work with integers, you can use this standard to define your own routine, but you have to define what is Inf and what is NaN in integer logic.

Comment: Interesting. So could I return +Inf/-Inf/Nan and avoid the divide by zero exception thrown by the FPU?

Comment: That's an option allowed by the standard, yes.

Comment: @bugspy: the default should be that the FPU doesn't throw exceptions. If you are asking about FP, what is your platform?

Answer (score 7):

Since you're ask for C++ specifically, you can do

```
pair< int, bool > safe_div( int lhs, int rhs ) {
    if ( rhs == 0 || lhs == INT_MIN && rhs == -1 ) return make_pair(0, false);
    else return make_pair( lhs/rhs, true );
}
```

alternately with `boost::optional`

```
optional<int> safe_div( int lhs, int rhs ) {
    if ( rhs == 0 || lhs == INT_MIN && rhs == -1 ) return optional<int>();
    else return lhs/rhs;
}
```

I'm assuming you want an integer operation and I added a check for overflow.

Answer (score 1):

i'm assuming this is for ints as ieee floats already fix this

the trouble is what value might be 'reasonable' depends on use so you will need to pass it in e.g.

```
DivOrDefault(int a, int b, int def)
{
    if (b == 0) return def;
    return a/b;
}
```

alternatively you can signal inf/Nan either in band (you could wrap the int in a struct which also has a bool for inf and or nan ) or out of band (as m_pGaldiator suggested)

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value as an output parameter. The function return type could be bool and you return true on success and false on division by zero. Then you simply check for true after the function. But the modern approach is to throw exception instead and catch it in your client code. Then you can choose to ignore it if you want.